# Django : cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {} giving me unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str' error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-settings, django-sessions

I'm trying to create a cart with django.

I created a class:

```
class Cart(object):
def __init__(self, request):
    self.session = request.session
    cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)

    if not cart:
        cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
    
    self.cart = cart
```

and it raises to me unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str' error.

My settings.py:

```
CART_SESSION_ID = 'cart'
```

My cart.py

```
from django.conf import settings

from Products.models import Product

class Cart(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.session = request.session
        cart = self.session.get(settings.CART_SESSION_ID)
        if not cart:
            cart = self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = {}
        self.cart = cart
    
    def __iter__(self):
        for p in self.cart.keys():
            self.cart[str(p)]['product'] = Product.objects.get(pk=p)
    
    def __len__(self):
        return sum(item['quantity'] for item in self.cart.values())
    
    def save(self):
        self.session[settings.CART_SESSION_ID] = self.cart
        self.session.modified = True
    
    def add(self, product_id, quantity=1, update_quantity=False):
        product_id = str(product_id)

        if product_id not in self.cart:
            self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': 1, 'id': product_id}
        
        if update_quantity:
            self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] += int(quantity)

            if self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] == 0:
                self.remove(product_id)
            
        self.save()
    
    def remove(self, product_id):
        if product_id in self.cart:
            del self.cart[product_id]
            self.save()
```

My Views.py:

```
def add_to_cart(request,product_id):
cart = Cart(request)
cart.add(product_id)

return render(request,'menu_cart.html')
```

I don't know what is wrong with the code.

## Edit:

Full Traceback:

```
    TypeError at /
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 4.0.4
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
Exception Location: C:\Users\dirim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\middleware.py, line 53, in process_response
Python Executable:  C:\Users\dirim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.10
Python Path:    
['E:\\Dev\\byGobi RF',
 'C:\\Users\\dirim\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\dirim\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\dirim\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\dirim\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\dirim\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 15 Jun 2022 18:39:46 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\Users\dirim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 55, in inner
                response = get_response(request) …
Local vars
C:\Users\dirim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py, line 136, in __call__
            response = self.process_response(request, response) …
Local vars
C:\Users\dirim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\middleware.py, line 53, in process_response
                    expires_time = time.time() + max_age …
Local vars
Request information
USER
AnonymousUser

GET
No GET data

POST
No POST data

FILES
No FILES data

COOKIES
Variable    Value
cart    
'{}'
csrftoken   
'2WVGzPyidIsa6LP5Fn8bVHZmtI1QDONsVRUyaq4u8fGp0KTjTPnR1fFubjXCBlYI'
META
Variable    Value
ALLUSERSPROFILE 
'C:\\ProgramData'
APPDATA 
'C:\\Users\\dirim\\AppData\\Roaming'
CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME   
'\\\\.\\pipe\\crashpad_11920_DHTWEFQRMNZOKAMV'
COLORTERM   
'truecolor'
COMMONPROGRAMFILES  
'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files'
COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86) 
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files'
COMMONPROGRAMW6432  
'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files'
COMPUTERNAME    
'BERKANT'
COMSPEC 
'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe'
CONTENT_LENGTH  
''
CONTENT_TYPE    
'text/plain'
CSRF_COOKIE 
'2WVGzPyidIsa6LP5Fn8bVHZmtI1QDONsVRUyaq4u8fGp0KTjTPnR1fFubjXCBlYI'
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE  
'byGobi.settings'
DRIVERDATA  
'C:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers\\DriverData'
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   
'CGI/1.1'
HOMEDRIVE   
'C:'
HOMEPATH    
'\\Users\\dirim'
HTTP_ACCEPT 
'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9'
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    
'gzip, deflate, br'
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    
'tr-TR'
HTTP_CONNECTION 
'keep-alive'
HTTP_COOKIE 
('cart={}; '
 'csrftoken=2WVGzPyidIsa6LP5Fn8bVHZmtI1QDONsVRUyaq4u8fGp0KTjTPnR1fFubjXCBlYI')
HTTP_HOST   
'127.0.0.1:8000'
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST 
'document'
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE 
'navigate'
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE 
'none'
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_USER 
'?1'
HTTP_SEC_GPC    
'1'
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS  
'1'
HTTP_USER_AGENT 
('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like '
 'Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.115 Safari/537.36')
LANG    
'tr_TR.UTF-8'
LOCALAPPDATA    
'C:\\Users\\dirim\\AppData\\Local'
LOGONSERVER 
'\\\\BERKANT'
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS    
'4'
ONEDRIVE    
'C:\\Users\\dirim\\OneDrive'
ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP    
'undefined'
OS  
'Windows_NT'
PATH    
('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NVIDIA Corporation\\PhysX\\Common;C:\\Program Files '
 '(x86)\\Common '
 'Files\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\;C:\\Users\\dirim\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\Scripts\\;C:\\Users\\dirim\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\;C:\\Users\\dirim\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;;C:\\Users\\dirim\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft '
 'VS Code\\bin')
PATHEXT 
'.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.CPL'
PATH_INFO   
'/'
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE  
'AMD64'
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER    
'AMD64 Family 23 Model 17 Stepping 0, AuthenticAMD'
PROCESSOR_LEVEL 
'23'
PROCESSOR_REVISION  
'1100'
PROGRAMDATA 
'C:\\ProgramData'
PROGRAMFILES    
'C:\\Program Files'
PROGRAMFILES(X86)   
'C:\\Program Files (x86)'
PROGRAMW6432    
'C:\\Program Files'
PSMODULEPATH    
('C:\\Users\\dirim\\Documents\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules;C:\\Program '
 'Files\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules')
PUBLIC  
'C:\\Users\\Public'
QUERY_STRING    
''
REMOTE_ADDR 
'127.0.0.1'
REMOTE_HOST 
''
REQUEST_METHOD  
'GET'
RUN_MAIN    
'true'
SCRIPT_NAME 
''
SERVER_NAME 
'Berkant'
SERVER_PORT 
'8000'
SERVER_PROTOCOL 
'HTTP/1.1'
SERVER_SOFTWARE 
'WSGIServer/0.2'
SESSIONNAME 
'Console'
SYSTEMDRIVE 
'C:'
SYSTEMROOT  
'C:\\WINDOWS'
TEMP    
'C:\\Users\\dirim\\AppData\\Local\\Temp'
TERM_PROGRAM    
'vscode'
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION    
'1.68.1'
TMP 
'C:\\Users\\dirim\\AppData\\Local\\Temp'
USERDOMAIN  
'BERKANT'
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE   
'BERKANT'
USERNAME    
'dirim'
USERPROFILE 
'C:\\Users\\dirim'
WINDIR  
'C:\\WINDOWS'
wsgi.errors 
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
wsgi.file_wrapper   
<class 'wsgiref.util.FileWrapper'>
wsgi.input  
<django.core.handlers.wsgi.LimitedStream object at 0x0000023B90CF61C0>
wsgi.multiprocess   
False
wsgi.multithread    
True
wsgi.run_once   
False
wsgi.url_scheme 
'http'
wsgi.version    
(1, 0)
Settings
Using settings module byGobi.settings
Setting Value
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES  
{}
ADMINS  
[]
ALLOWED_HOSTS   
[]
APPEND_SLASH    
True
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS 
['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS    
'********************'
AUTH_USER_MODEL 
'auth.User'
BASE_DIR    
WindowsPath('E:/Dev/byGobi RF')
CACHES  
{'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS  
'default'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX 
'********************'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS    
600
CART_SESSION_ID 
'cart'
CSRF_COOKIE_AGE 
31449600
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN  
None
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY    
False
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME    
'csrftoken'
CSRF_COOKIE_PATH    
'/'
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE    
'Lax'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE  
False
CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW   
'django.views.csrf.csrf_failure'
CSRF_HEADER_NAME    
'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS    
[]
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS   
False
DATABASES   
{'default': {'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
             'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
             'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
             'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
             'HOST': '',
             'NAME': WindowsPath('E:/Dev/byGobi RF/db.sqlite3'),
             'OPTIONS': {},
             'PASSWORD': '********************',
             'PORT': '',
             'TEST': {'CHARSET': None,
                      'COLLATION': None,
                      'MIGRATE': True,
                      'MIRROR': None,
                      'NAME': None},
             'TIME_ZONE': None,
             'USER': ''}}
DATABASE_ROUTERS    
[]
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE 
2621440
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS   
1000
DATETIME_FORMAT 
'N j, Y, P'
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M']
DATE_FORMAT 
'N j, Y'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS  
['%Y-%m-%d',
 '%m/%d/%Y',
 '%m/%d/%y',
 '%b %d %Y',
 '%b %d, %Y',
 '%d %b %Y',
 '%d %b, %Y',
 '%B %d %Y',
 '%B %d, %Y',
 '%d %B %Y',
 '%d %B, %Y']
DEBUG   
True
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS  
False
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR   
'.'
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD  
'django.db.models.AutoField'
DEFAULT_CHARSET 
'utf-8'
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER  
'django.views.debug.ExceptionReporter'
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER   
'django.views.debug.SafeExceptionReporterFilter'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE    
'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL  
'webmaster@localhost'
DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE    
''
DEFAULT_TABLESPACE  
''
DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS  
[]
EMAIL_BACKEND   
'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST  
'localhost'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD 
'********************'
EMAIL_HOST_USER 
''
EMAIL_PORT  
25
EMAIL_SSL_CERTFILE  
None
EMAIL_SSL_KEYFILE   
'********************'
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX    
'[Django] '
EMAIL_TIMEOUT   
None
EMAIL_USE_LOCALTIME 
False
EMAIL_USE_SSL   
False
EMAIL_USE_TLS   
False
FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS   
None
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS    
['django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler',
 'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler']
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE 
2621440
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS 
420
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR    
None
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK   
0
FIXTURE_DIRS    
[]
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME   
None
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH  
None
FORM_RENDERER   
'django.forms.renderers.DjangoTemplates'
IGNORABLE_404_URLS  
[]
INSTALLED_APPS  
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'byGobi',
 'Accounts',
 'Cart',
 'Products',
 'Shop',
 'Pages',
 'Dashboard']
INTERNAL_IPS    
[]
LANGUAGES   
[('af', 'Afrikaans'),
 ('ar', 'Arabic'),
 ('ar-dz', 'Algerian Arabic'),
 ('ast', 'Asturian'),
 ('az', 'Azerbaijani'),
 ('bg', 'Bulgarian'),
 ('be', 'Belarusian'),
 ('bn', 'Bengali'),
 ('br', 'Breton'),
 ('bs', 'Bosnian'),
 ('ca', 'Catalan'),
 ('cs', 'Czech'),
 ('cy', 'Welsh'),
 ('da', 'Danish'),
 ('de', 'German'),
 ('dsb', 'Lower Sorbian'),
 ('el', 'Greek'),
 ('en', 'English'),
 ('en-au', 'Australian English'),
 ('en-gb', 'British English'),
 ('eo', 'Esperanto'),
 ('es', 'Spanish'),
 ('es-ar', 'Argentinian Spanish'),
 ('es-co', 'Colombian Spanish'),
 ('es-mx', 'Mexican Spanish'),
 ('es-ni', 'Nicaraguan Spanish'),
 ('es-ve', 'Venezuelan Spanish'),
 ('et', 'Estonian'),
 ('eu', 'Basque'),
 ('fa', 'Persian'),
 ('fi', 'Finnish'),
 ('fr', 'French'),
 ('fy', 'Frisian'),
 ('ga', 'Irish'),
 ('gd', 'Scottish Gaelic'),
 ('gl', 'Galician'),
 ('he', 'Hebrew'),
 ('hi', 'Hindi'),
 ('hr', 'Croatian'),
 ('hsb', 'Upper Sorbian'),
 ('hu', 'Hungarian'),
 ('hy', 'Armenian'),
 ('ia', 'Interlingua'),
 ('id', 'Indonesian'),
 ('ig', 'Igbo'),
 ('io', 'Ido'),
 ('is', 'Icelandic'),
 ('it', 'Italian'),
 ('ja', 'Japanese'),
 ('ka', 'Georgian'),
 ('kab', 'Kabyle'),
 ('kk', 'Kazakh'),
 ('km', 'Khmer'),
 ('kn', 'Kannada'),
 ('ko', 'Korean'),
 ('ky', 'Kyrgyz'),
 ('lb', 'Luxembourgish'),
 ('lt', 'Lithuanian'),
 ('lv', 'Latvian'),
 ('mk', 'Macedonian'),
 ('ml', 'Malayalam'),
 ('mn', 'Mongolian'),
 ('mr', 'Marathi'),
 ('ms', 'Malay'),
 ('my', 'Burmese'),
 ('nb', 'Norwegian Bokmål'),
 ('ne', 'Nepali'),
 ('nl', 'Dutch'),
 ('nn', 'Norwegian Nynorsk'),
 ('os', 'Ossetic'),
 ('pa', 'Punjabi'),
 ('pl', 'Polish'),
 ('pt', 'Portuguese'),
 ('pt-br', 'Brazilian Portuguese'),
 ('ro', 'Romanian'),
 ('ru', 'Russian'),
 ('sk', 'Slovak'),
 ('sl', 'Slovenian'),
 ('sq', 'Albanian'),
 ('sr', 'Serbian'),
 ('sr-latn', 'Serbian Latin'),
 ('sv', 'Swedish'),
 ('sw', 'Swahili'),
 ('ta', 'Tamil'),
 ('te', 'Telugu'),
 ('tg', 'Tajik'),
 ('th', 'Thai'),
 ('tk', 'Turkmen'),
 ('tr', 'Turkish'),
 ('tt', 'Tatar'),
 ('udm', 'Udmurt'),
 ('uk', 'Ukrainian'),
 ('ur', 'Urdu'),
 ('uz', 'Uzbek'),
 ('vi', 'Vietnamese'),
 ('zh-hans', 'Simplified Chinese'),
 ('zh-hant', 'Traditional Chinese')]
LANGUAGES_BIDI  
['he', 'ar', 'ar-dz', 'fa', 'ur']
LANGUAGE_CODE   
'en-us'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_AGE 
None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_DOMAIN  
None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_HTTPONLY    
False
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME    
'django_language'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_PATH    
'/'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_SAMESITE    
None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_SECURE  
False
LOCALE_PATHS    
[]
LOGGING 
{}
LOGGING_CONFIG  
'logging.config.dictConfig'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL  
'/accounts/profile/'
LOGIN_URL   
'/accounts/login/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL 
None
MANAGERS    
[]
MEDIA_ROOT  
'E:\\Dev\\byGobi RF\\media'
MEDIA_URL   
'/media/'
MESSAGE_STORAGE 
'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'
MIDDLEWARE  
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
MIGRATION_MODULES   
{}
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT    
'F j'
NUMBER_GROUPING 
0
PASSWORD_HASHERS    
'********************'
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT  
'********************'
PREPEND_WWW 
False
ROOT_URLCONF    
'byGobi.urls'
SECRET_KEY  
'********************'
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF 
True
SECURE_CROSS_ORIGIN_OPENER_POLICY   
'same-origin'
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS  
False
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD 
False
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS 
0
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER 
None
SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT  
[]
SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY  
'same-origin'
SECURE_SSL_HOST 
None
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT 
False
SERVER_EMAIL    
'root@localhost'
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS 
'default'
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE  
'86400'
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN   
None
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY 
True
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME 
'sessionid'
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH 
'/'
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE 
'Lax'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE   
False
SESSION_ENGINE  
'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE 
False
SESSION_FILE_PATH   
None
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST  
False
SESSION_SERIALIZER  
'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'
SETTINGS_MODULE 
'byGobi.settings'
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT   
'm/d/Y P'
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT   
'm/d/Y'
SIGNING_BACKEND 
'django.core.signing.TimestampSigner'
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS  
[]
STATICFILES_DIRS    
['E:\\Dev\\byGobi RF\\static/']
STATICFILES_FINDERS 
['django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder']
STATICFILES_STORAGE 
'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT 
None
STATIC_URL  
'/static/'
TEMPLATES   
[{'APP_DIRS': True,
  'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
  'DIRS': ['templates'],
  'OPTIONS': {'context_processors': ['django.template.context_processors.debug',
                                     'django.template.context_processors.request',
                                     'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                                     'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                                     'byGobi.context_processors.cart']}}]
TEST_NON_SERIALIZED_APPS    
[]
TEST_RUNNER 
'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
','
TIME_FORMAT 
'P'
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
['%H:%M:%S', '%H:%M:%S.%f', '%H:%M']
TIME_ZONE   
'UTC'
USE_DEPRECATED_PYTZ 
False
USE_I18N    
True
USE_L10N    
True
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
False
USE_TZ  
True
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST    
False
USE_X_FORWARDED_PORT    
False
WSGI_APPLICATION    
'byGobi.wsgi.application'
X_FRAME_OPTIONS 
'DENY'
YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT   
'F Y'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely you have set the [**`SESSION_COOKIE_AGE`** setting <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#session-cookie-age) as a string, like `'1209600'`, whereas it should be a number, so:

```
# settings.py

SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 1209600  # 🖘 not a string (i.e. not '1209600')
```